# Change output location of angular-errors.log

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am running `ng build` in a Docker container and am getting a failed build with the advice to "See /tmp/ng-LHvuYx/angular-errors.log"

I can't see that file because once the build process finishes, the container stops.

Is there a way to tell `ng build` to put angular-errors.log in the current working directory (or any directory of my choosing)? I realise I could map /tmp into the container but I want the convenience of having angular-errors.log show up in my current working directory as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not yet.

But you could set the Path for your OS temp directory before executing build like:

`set TEMP=C:\myAngularTemp && ng build`

I did not find a possibility yet to pass it directly to angular-cli as far as I can see in angular-cli sources for angular 10.0.x although it looks kind of prepared:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/10.0.x/packages/angular/cli/utilities/log-file.ts

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/search?q=logPath&unscoped_q=logPath

```
let logPath: string | undefined;
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. If you need to read the `angular-errors.log` file you could just print its content to the output using something like this

```
cat $(find / -name "angular-errors.log")
```